# jQuery load url, getScript to load 2 scripts. makes me refresh dialog 2 times before it works

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, getscript

Using jQuery and loading a url. and then I use getScript() to load ckeditor plugin.
The problem is I have to open/close the dialog 2-3 times before the textarea shows up with the ckeditor. I have no idea why.

```
$(divId).load(Url, function () {
    $.when(
        $.getScript('//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/standard/ckeditor.js'),
        $.getScript('//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/full-all/adapters/jquery.js', function() {
            $( 'textarea.richtext' ).ckeditor({
                customConfig: '/ckeditor_config_simple.js'
            });
         })
    ).done(function(){
        console.log("test 123 ");
    });
});
```

Comment: What purpose of using a deferred object here? And you should load jq adapters from ckeditor getScript() success callback. And what about error message in console???

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ckeditor is not a function(…)

Answer (score 1):

You are loading both ckeditor and adapter at the same time, so since adapter is smaller, it loads first but fires an error because ckeditor must be loaded before adapter.

**UPDATE:** Since you use a Jquery UI dialog for div, try this:

```
$(divId).dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) {
     $(this).load(URL, function() {
        $.getScript('//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/standard/ckeditor.js')
        .then(function() {
            return $.getScript('//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/full-all/adapters/jquery.js');
        })
        .then(function() {
            $( 'textarea.richtext' ).ckeditor({
                customConfig: '/ckeditor_config_simple.js'
            });
        });
    });
   }
});
```

Comment: No errors but now the textArea is not displaying the richtext editor. Looks just line a normal textarea

Comment: Is the textarea inside the url you load or outside? How do you use the load function?

Comment: yes, inside...$(divId).load(myDialogUrl, function () {

weird note, if i place the "'textarea.richtext' ).ckeditor({" inside a js file and then getScript for that file it works. lol

Comment: Where is your load function in your page? Before or after your div? Are you wrapping it in $(function() { ...} ? Did you wait for ckeditor to be loaded because it takes some seconds and during that time all you see is the textarea.

Comment: the load is after the "$(divId).dialog("open");"
And yes.  after the dialog loads for a split second i do see is just the textarea before the richtext loads...which is quite annoying too..that flicker

Comment: See my updated answer. However, if you open the dialog with a button click or something else, you could just load ckeditor and adapter when the page loads, to save you the delay.